# How to change JDK version from 1.6 to 1.7 in liberty?

Tags: java, java-7, websphere-liberty

I am using websphere 8.5 liberty server to deploy my .EAR application . After running  `java -version` command i can see

```
Java version "1.6.0_38"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IceTea6 1.13.10) (rhe1-1.13.10.0.e17_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-bo1, mixed mode)
```

Now i just want to change the Java version to `1.7` . Should  websphere 8.5 liberty server support 1.7 and 1.8 ? How can i change the path ? Please proved any steps .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websphere Liberty supports 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 JVM from different vendors (IBM, Oracle). If you want to point it do the specific JVM just create `server.env` file in the server directory and define `JAVA_HOME` variable there like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\wlp\java
```

Running `java -version` doesn't tell you anything about JVM used by Liberty, as it just is using default Java from the system. You can see which JVM is used by Liberty in the `messages.log` e.g.:

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.9/wlp-1.0.12.cl50920160227-1523) 
on IBM J9 VM, version pwi3280sr1ifx-20150513_01 (SR1+IX90162+IV73188 SR1+IX90162+IV73188) (en_us)
```

You can also download latest Liberty bundled with Java8 from here https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/runtimes-webprofile7-ibm-java

Comment: I can see the logs from messages.log `[root@logs]# cat messages.log
********************************************************************************
product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.8 (wlp-1.0.11.cl50820151201-1942)
wlp.install.dir = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.38.x86_64/jre
java.version = 1.6.0_38
java.runtime = OpenJDK Runtime Environment (1.6.0_38-b38)
os = Linux (3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64; amd64) (en_US)'

Comment: So is this using `JDK 1.6` . Isn't ?

Comment: @stack_555 - yes it is. Just install newer Java and point to it via that `server.env` file or download Liberty bundled with Java8.

Comment: I have done with `su -c "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk" ` command . After installing it pointed to JDK 1.7 . Thanks !!!

Comment: Support for Java 6 will end with the 17.0.0.3 release of WebSphere Liberty. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_remfeat.html

Answer (score 2):

under WLP directory create a new directory called "etc".
inside the etc directory , create a file called "server.env"
open server.env file for editing and add the following

```
JAVA_HOME={path_to_java}
```

This sets the java for all the servers you create under that liberty installation.

if you want to customize at server level , then create the server.env file under the server home location wlp/usr/servers/{server_name} , with the same contents as described abovev

Answer (score 0):

WAS Liberty doesn't bundle a version of Java and can run using any certified Java such as the system Java or any Java that you have defined in your environment. Liberty will use the Java specified in the JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME environment variables before using a Java that may be found in the PATH. Further information can be found in README.txt that provided in the root directory of your Liberty installation.

Comment: It is not recommended to mess with the provided scripts. The correct way to customize JDK is via `server.env` file - see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html

Comment: @Gas - My feedback above isn't to change anything in the server script. The wording is straight from the WAS Liberty README.txt which instructs the users to specify either the JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME variables (or default to the java on the path). It does not say to change anything in the script.

Comment: ok, so just edit your post explaining that one can set system JAVA_HOME variable, that will be taken by the script automatically, and not change the script itself.